# Populating table with 2 arrays

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

***I'm trying to populate a tableview controller with objects from 2 different arrays but it crashes and gives this error 
    "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]"***

***how do i fix this? below is my code:***

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//[super viewDidAppear:<#animated#>];

NSManagedObjectContext  *bookmanagedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest  *bookfetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Book"];
NSPredicate *bookpredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" bookref.toproject contains[cd]%@",self.projectdb];
[bookfetchRequest setPredicate:bookpredicate];
NSSortDescriptor *booksortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"authorSurname" ascending:YES];
NSArray *booksortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:booksortDescriptor, nil];
[bookfetchRequest setSortDescriptors:booksortDescriptors];

self.BookrefArray = [[bookmanagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:bookfetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSManagedObjectContext  *journalmanagedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest  *journalfetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Journal"];
NSPredicate *journalpredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" journalref.toproj contains[cd]%@",self.projectdb];
[journalfetchRequest setPredicate:journalpredicate];
NSSortDescriptor *journalsortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"surname" ascending:YES];
NSArray *journalsortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:journalsortDescriptor, nil];
[journalfetchRequest setSortDescriptors:journalsortDescriptors];

self.JournalrefArray = [[journalmanagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:journalfetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
[self.tableView reloadData];}

(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return (self.BookrefArray.count + self.journalrefArray.count);
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cells";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Journal *myjournal =[self.journalrefArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[myjournal valueForKey:@"journalname"]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[myjournal valueForKey:@"surname"],[myjournal valueForKey:@"firstname"]]];
    Book *mybook =[self.BookrefArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[mybook valueForKey:@"bookTitle"]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[mybook valueForKey:@"authorSurname"],[mybook valueForKey:@"authorOthernames"]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about your arrays - where are they initialised?

Comment: i edited the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because you try to access of an element of your array that is not exist.

In fact you says that your table has "table1.count + table2.count" elements and for each cell you try to get an element in your 2 tables with the current row.
For example, if table1 has 2 items and table2 has 5 items
, your tableView will have 7 rows and "cellForRowAtIndexPath" will be called 7 times. So for index 3 you will obtains this error because your table1 has only 2 items.

To solve the problem, you should get a book OR a journal in function of this row.
For example, you can try anything like this :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cells";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (indexPath.row < self.BookrefArray.count)
  {
    Book *mybook =[self.BookrefArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure your cell with a book
  }
  else
  {
    Journal *myjournal =[self.journalrefArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - self.BookrefArray.count];
    // Configure your cell with a journal
  }

  return cell;
}
```

You can also change the order to display journals before books.

Comment: thanks that code works... but how to i get it to allow deletion of BookrefArray...using (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ???

Comment: Using the same method in the commitEditingStyle function, "if (indexPath.row < self.BookrefArray.cound) {} else {}" you can know with which array work and get the good object (book or array) to delete from the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**

You need to differentiate *Book* and *Journal* in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

**Explanation :**

Your call for tableview's `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be dependent upon the number you're returning from tableview's `-numberOfRowsInSection` method.

So, for example, you've **3** objects in *BookrefArray* and **2** objects in *journalrefArray*, your tableview's `-numberOfRowsInSection` method will return 5 which means `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called for 5 times.

Let's go through this line :

```
Journal *myjournal =[self.journalrefArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Here, it'll get `indexPath.row = 5` for one case, and your *journalrefArray* contains only **2** objects. So, you're getting `"index .. beyond bounds"` error.

**Update :**

You can simply merge both the arrays into one.

```
[documentsArray addObjectsFromArray:self.BookrefArray];
[documentsArray addObjectsFromArray:self.journalrefArray];
```

and then in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can do something like this :

```
id document = [documentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([document isKindOfClass:Book])
{
    Book *mybook = (Book *)document;
    // Do something with mybook.
}
else
{
    Journal *myjournal = (Journal *)document;
    // Do something with myjournal.
}
```

Comment: the thing is the number of objects depends on the inputs... and there's no limits to how many inputs... and indexPath.row = 5 doesn't work...